# SymmetricDS Error while creating Trigger on Oracle DB due to double quotes

Tags: oracle, symmetricds

I am using **SymmetricDS 3.12.8** trying to synchronize Oracle and PostgreSQL DBs. When SymmetricDS tries to create Oracle triggers it uses double quotes for schema and wrong table name and that is why it says it can't find the table

```
Error Msg = ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

The trigger creation:

```
create or replace trigger SYM_ON_I_FOR_SGN_TRC_NTTB_SGN after insert on "schema_name"."table_name"
```

What I need is to make SymmetricDS to remove double quotes from Oracle Dialect like this:

```
create or replace trigger SYM_ON_I_FOR_SGN_TRC_NTTB_SGN after insert on schema_name.table_name
```

Comment: The double quotes makes it case-sensitive, so if you're looking for lowercase objects, they would have to have been created that way in Oracle. If you can't get it to remove double quotes, try making sure it uses object names (schema, table, column, etc) in UPPERCASE. That'll probably work, assuming the objects were created without double quotes in Oracle, since that defaults them to uppercase in the dictionary.

Comment: @PaulW seems a logical solution and there are some changes. But still the issue is somewhere with SymmetricDB